# Date String conversion in Python and momentjs

Tags: python, momentjs

Folks,
  I am very bad with date formatting and standards.  What would be the pythonic way to convert the string `05/05/2015` to ISO 8601 `2015-05-05T00:00:00.000Z` ?
  I've found the moment.js alternative in python... [zachwill/moment](https://github.com/zachwill/moment) but I dont see a `moment().toISOString();`

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `time.strftime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
>>> arrow.get(timezone='UTC')
<Arrow [2015-03-08T18:42:06.629114+00:00]>
>>> str(arrow.get())
'2015-03-08T18:42:08.645550+00:00'
>>> arrow.get(tz='UTC').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS') + 'Z'
'2015-03-08T18:47:35.205Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the moment library linked above,

`start = moment.date('01/29/2015','MM/DD/YYYY').date`